# mock constructor and super injected field with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, powermockito

I hope the example code snippets are enough to rebuild my problem.

I Have a class `TreeWalker` and a sub class `ABCTreeWalker extends TreeWalker`.
I work with Spring Dependency Injection and in the `TreeWalker` I have a dependency `Helper helper;` which is protected and thus also available in the `ABCTreeWalker`. All dependencies like this `helper` are field-injected with Springs `@Autowired`, so there is no setter.

```
public class TreeWalker {

    @Autowired
    protected Helper helper;
}


public class ABCTreeWalker extends TreeWalker {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        String something = helper.getSomething();
        InstanceModel instanceModel = new InstanceModel(something);
        // ... more stuff ...
    }
}
```

I need to create a Unit-Test for the `ABCTreeWalker` class in which I need to do two things:

- Inject a mock of the `helper` into my `ABCTreeWalker` class under
  test
- mock the constructor call

My Test runs with the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` which allows to inject the `helper` with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` Annotations. BUT: In order to prepare for the constructor mock I need to prepare the Class under Test which is `ABCTreeWalker` with the annotation `@PrepareForTest(ABCTreeWalker.class)`. And if I do this, the injection won't happen anymore (I guess because it came from the super class).

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ABCTreeWalker.class)
public class ABCTreeWalkerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ABCTreeWalker abcTreeWalker;

    @Mock
    private Helper helper;

    @Test
    public void testVisitGui() throws Exception {
        // ... more stuff ...
        when(helper.getSomething()).thenReturn("test");
        InstanceModel instanceModel = mock(InstanceModel.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(InstanceModel.class)
             .withArguments("test")
             .thenReturn(instanceModel);
        // ... more stuff ...

        abcTreeWalker.doSomething(); // execute

        // assertions etc.
 }
```

So what can I do now?

- I could inject the `helper` in my `ABCTreeWalker`, but that is redundant
- I probably could create a setter, but that would only for the test
- I can't rmeove Powermock because of the constructor mocking

Do you guys have suggestions?

Comment: what are u getting without @PrepareForTest(ABCTreeWalker.class)

Comment: Then the injection works, but I can't mock the constructor call anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you think about a @Autowired constructor

```
public class TreeWalker {
protected Helper helper;

@Autowired
public TreeWalker(Helper helper){
    this.helper = helper;
}
```

}
And then call the super() in the constructor of the child?

Comment: I am only able to change the child class, the super class comes from a maven depedency. I work on a "custom solution" of a "standard product", where I can't change the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong class. The constructor could be for ABCTreeWalker class. 
`public class ABCTreeWalker  {

@Autowired
public ABCTreeWalker (Helper helper){
    this.helper = helper;
}`